# Keeping an Activity title set to the title of the active Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've set up an app with a `ViewPager` wrapped around a custom implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. However, I'd like to update the title in the `ActionBar` based on the primary fragment. Here's some code, from the `FragmentAdapter`:

```
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int pos, Object object) {
    this.cur = pos;
    getItem(pos).onPrimary(pos);
}
```

From the `Activity`:

```
public void setTitle(int pos, String title) {
    if (pos == this.fa.cur) { // this.fa is the FragmentAdapter
        super.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

And from one of my `Fragment`s:

```
public void onPrimary(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
    if (this.activity != null && this.title != null)
        this.activity.setTitle(pos, this.title);
}

private void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    if (this.activity != null && this.title != null)
        this.activity.setTitle(this.pos, title);
}
```

While this seems to work after a clean start, it starts to fall down in some cases; particularly when the fragments have been destroyed and are then rebuilt, it seems. Does anyone have a better/cleaner/simpler solution for this?